# xcode managed profile shows wrong name

Tags: ios, xcode8, provisioning-profile

Hy,
Whenever I enable automatic manage signing, then Xcode managed profile shows wrong profile name. It always shows iOS Team Provisioning profile instead of created on apple developer portal.
Please look at the below image:

[image]

All 5 ticks are correct, selected team is correct but why it shows iOS Team provisioning profile>

Answer (score 0):

You have to force download all profiles and certificate:

Please follow below steps:

```
 xCode -> Prefrences -> Accounts -> Select Account -> View Details -> Download All
```

Comment: Xcode not downloading 3 provisionings, although i clicked on Download ALL.

Comment: @KetanShinde if it is successfully created and you said it is not downloading then try Quit Xcode and try again it will work. and if not then do let me know

Comment: i means it's not downloading from path mentioned but yes successfully created on a developer portal. Another strange thing i found there isn't any  provisioning profile named iOS team on a developer portal, but xocde showing two more provisioning profile 'iOS team'-etc on above path,

Comment: yes i have force quit xcode, but strange, it same issue

Comment: Maybe I am using Xcode 8.0. can be little buggy I'll update after downloading Xcode 8.2.1. Thanks!